# pgfplots: How to use a different marker style for each point within one graph? If possible, style specified in csv file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot data from a csv file, but plot each data point in a specific style (different color, size and mark shape).

Is it e.g. possible to define the mark style in the csv file additonally? Or to create something as \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist, just that the marks **within one plot** take the specified styles?

I am helpful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide any examples, so I do not know the kind of plot you are after. But maybe this code can be useful if you have a [scatter plot](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-2dplots#sec-16.12):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.csv}
a,b,c,d,mystyle
1,4,5,1,stylea
2,3,1,5,stylea
3,5,6,1,styleb
4,1,4,9,styleb
5,3,4,7,styleb
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot [scatter,
        % no comma after the last class!
        % see https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-2dplots#sec-16.12
        scatter/classes={stylea={blue, mark=triangle*}, styleb={red}},
        only marks, mark size=4pt,
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ] table [x=a, y=c, col sep=comma, meta=mystyle] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my issue!

My bad, I assumed it was clear that a scatter plot was meant - but you are right, it was not. Still you gave the perfect answer :)